# Given $a_n=\cos(\pi n + \frac{\pi}{n})$, should I use Heine definition to limit in order to show that $a_n$ is not convergent?

Tags: calculus

On one hand, $a_n$ is a sequence. On the other, $\cos$ is a function. So, is $a_n$  a sequence defined by the cosine function? Or, is it a sequence defined by the cosine sequence? If we see cosine here as a sequence, how can we talk about the composition of cosine with the sequence inside cosine when $n\to \infty$?

Any expert here to explain what are the differences between functions and sequences and why can't we apply functions theorems on sequences? For example why limit of sequence composition is not defined well? like $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n(b_n)$.

Heine's definition of limit:
$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ if and only if for all sequences $x_n$ (with $x_n$ not equal to $a$ for all $n$) converging to $a$ the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $L$.

Comment: $a_n$ is a sequence, that is defined using the cosine function : namely by applying it to $n\pi + \frac \pi n$. So the question of seeing cosine as a sequence, and the subsequent question, does not come into the context.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Why cosine can't be counted as a sequence? for example $\cos_n(n)$ so, $\cos_1=\cos(1), \cos_2=\cos(2)$...the only problem I see is when we talk about limits and the cosine gets a sequence as a parameter. Because there is no rule for composition of two sequences

Comment: @MorHaham See this : https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Composite_Function

Comment: I didn't write that we don't have a rule for limit of functions composition. I wrote that we don't have it for sequences.

Comment: A sequence iof real numbers is by definition a mapping from $\mathbb N$ into $\mathbb R.$ $n\to \cos (\pi n+\pi/n)$ is such a mapping. Thus $a_n$ is a sequence.

Comment: If $\cos$ is a sequence, why can we calculate the limit inside $\cos$ before applying $\cos$ as we do with functions? We have only rule for limit of composite functions. $\cos(\pi n + \pi/n)$ is a composite sequences.

Comment: @MorHaham That, is  not cosine being counted as a sequence, but rather cosine, the *function* cosine, being applied  on a sequence , namely the sequence $1,2,3,...$. I still do not see where the cosine "sequence" comes from. There is no way of *composing* sequences : if I give you two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$, how do you "compose" them? I can see where the word composite comes from, since $\cos$ , the function, is being composed with a sequence , which is a function from $\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: In answer to your problem of "composition of two functions", indeed *there are* criteria under which the composition of two sequences can be deemed convergent or not : and that is if the second function is continuous, in which case studying the first function is deemed enough. Also, please clarify what is "Heine" definition of convergence of sequences, so that we can get the question better.

Comment: Let $a_n = n, b_n = n^2$. So $c_n = a_n(b_n)$. The question is, why is it not defined well? and if it is, why we don't have a rule for limit of composite sequences? Can you clarify what are the differences between sequences and functions and why can't we apply functions theorems on sequences without the definition of Heine?

Comment: @MorHaham Let $a_n = \cos(\pi n + \frac{\pi}{n})$ then $a_1 = \cos(\pi \times 1 + \frac{\pi}{1})$ , $a_2 = \cos(\pi \times 2 + \frac{\pi}{2})$ and so on . Here we put number $n$ to $b_n = \pi n + \frac{\pi}{n}$ and get the result . It can be any real number . After that , we put the result to $\cos$ function . The answer is our desired term of $a_n$ .

Answer (score 3):

$a_n=\cos(\pi n + \frac{\pi}{n}) = \cos(\pi n)\cos(\frac{\pi}{n}) - \sin(\pi n)\sin(\frac{\pi}{n}) = (-1)^n \cos(\frac{\pi}{n})$

$n = 2k \to a_n = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2k}) $

$n = 2k-1 \to a_n = -\cos(\frac{\pi}{2k-1})$

Limit of the first sequence is $1$ and the second sequence is $-1$ . So $a_n$ is divergent .

Comment: This is not what I asked.

Comment: @MorHaham Please check it again .

Comment: How do you calculate the limit of $a_n$? It's a composition of two sequences. that's why we have to use Heine definition for limits. You can't just calculate the limit of the sequence inside $\cos$ and then apply the cosine because there is no composition rule for sequences.

Comment: If $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$ then we can say $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = f(L)$ if $f$ is continuous at $L$ .

Comment: Ok, that's Heine. You didn't mention that. Notice that my question was if I should use Heine, as we can't do it just by sequences rules. can we?...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Heine's definition . For solving that question we need to Heine's definition as you wrote .